# How to filter React state based on the value of 3 select dropdowns?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a set of user data that can be filtered by 3 select dropdowns which filter by location, department, and client.

I am running into some edge case issues where if multiple dropdowns have been selected and I make a change to one that is not set to "All" the users are not properly filtered.

Here is a sample set of user data that is set to the "users" state:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "Sissy",
        "last_name": "Chatterton",
        "email": "schatterton0@pcworld.com",
        "bgImg": "http://dummyimage.com/500x1000.png/cc0000/ffffff",
        "profile_photo": "http://dummyimage.com/100x100.png/ff4444/ffffff",
        "title": "Statistician IV",
        "department": "Marketing",
        "city": "New York City",
        "state": "NY",
        "phone": "212-447-7193",
        "quote": "Donec ut mauris eget massa tempor convallis.",
        "quoteAuthor": "Sissy Chatterton",
        "client": "Skinder"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "first_name": "Kelcie",
        "last_name": "Shildrake",
        "email": "kshildrake1@usatoday.com",
        "bgImg": "http://dummyimage.com/500x1000.png/ff4444/ffffff",
        "profile_photo": "http://dummyimage.com/100x100.png/ff4444/ffffff",
        "title": "Librarian",
        "department": "Human Resources",
        "city": "New York City",
        "state": "NY",
        "phone": "212-694-8464",
        "quote": "Aliquam non mauris. Morbi non lectus.",
        "quoteAuthor": "Kelcie Shildrake",
        "client": "Twitterworks"
    },
}
```

This is the markup for the select dropdowns:

```
const UserSearchBox = ({ handleSelectChange, handleInputChange, locations, departments, clients, locationValue, clientValue, departmentValue }) => {
    return (
        <form className="user-search">
            <input className="user-input" placeholder="Search for Peeps by name" name="userSearch" onChange={handleInputChange} />

            <div>
                <select id="locationSelect" defaultValue={locationValue} value={locationValue} onChange={handleSelectChange}>
                    <option data-filter-type="location" value="all">All</option>
                    {locations.map((x) => {
                        return(
                            <option data-filter-type="location" value={x}>{x}</option>
                        )
                    })}
                </select>

                <select id="departmentSelect" defaultValue={departmentValue} value={departmentValue} onChange={handleSelectChange}>
                    <option data-filter-type="department" value="all">All</option>
                    {departments.map((x) => {
                        return(
                            <option data-filter-type="department" value={x}>{x}</option>
                        )
                    })}
                </select>

                <select id="clientSelect" defaultValue={clientValue} value={clientValue} onChange={handleSelectChange}>
                    <option data-filter-type="client" value="all">All</option>
                    {clients.map((x) => {
                        return(
                            <option data-filter-type="client" value={x}>{x}</option>
                        )
                    })}
                </select>
            </div>


        </form>
    )
}
```

And finally the code that is trying to filter the users with the onChange Handler:

```
 const [users, setUsers] = useState<User[]>([])
    const [allUsers, setAllUsers] = useState<User[]>([])
    const [locationFilter, setLocationFilter] = useState('all')
    const [clientFilter, setClientFilter] = useState('all')
    const [departmentFilter, setDepartmentFilter] = useState('all')

const handleSelectChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let searchTerm = e.target.value;
        let attr = e.target[e.target.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-filter-type')

        const filterHandler = (value, userSet) => {
            setUsers(userSet.filter((x) =>
                (x.city || '').toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
            ))
        }

        const multipleFilterHandler = () => {
            setUsers(allUsers)

            if (locationFilter !== 'all') {
                setUsers(users.filter((x) =>
                    (x.city || '').toLowerCase().includes(locationFilter.toLowerCase())
                ))
            }
            if (clientFilter !== 'all') {
                setUsers(users.filter((x) =>
                    (x.client || '').toLowerCase().includes(clientFilter.toLowerCase())
                ))
            }
            if (departmentFilter !== 'all') {
                alert("this ran")
                setUsers(users.filter((x) =>
                    (x.department || '').toLowerCase().includes(departmentFilter.toLowerCase())
                ))
            }
        }



        if (searchTerm !== "all" && users) {
            switch (attr) {
                case 'location':
                    setLocationFilter(searchTerm)
                    if (clientFilter === 'all' && departmentFilter === 'all') {
                        filterHandler(searchTerm, allUsers)
                    } else {
                        multipleFilterHandler()
                    }
                    break;
                case 'department':
                    setDepartmentFilter(searchTerm)
                    if (clientFilter === 'all' && locationFilter === 'all') {
                        filterHandler(searchTerm, allUsers)
                    } else {
                        filterHandler(searchTerm, users)
                    }
                    break;
                case 'client':
                    setClientFilter(searchTerm)
                    if (departmentFilter === 'all' && locationFilter === 'all') {
                        filterHandler(searchTerm, allUsers)
                    } else {
                        filterHandler(searchTerm, users)
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    setUsers(allUsers)
            }
        } else {
            setUsers(allUsers)
        }
    }
```

So one edge case that I've run into is where if I have a two dropdowns with a value selected and I change one of those two dropdowns to a different value, it won't work.

I attempted to make a function called multiplefilterhandler with logic where it would reset the users to allUsers(it's the initial data we receive of all users from the database) and then run through all three select dropdowns and filter based on whether the value was not equal to 'all'

This does not work since it breaks on the first if statement that is valid.

What would be the best approach to something like this, would having one function like multiplefilterhandler that runs in an if statement work? The challenge I'm facing is what to do when one of those filters is set to 'all' and the others are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would pull the `setUsers` out of your handler and into a `useEffect`. You could have it updated when any of the filters change. You only want to call it once, so you can apply each filter separately and set the final array at the end.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const filteredUsers = allUsers;
    if (locationFilter !== 'all') filteredUsers = filteredUsers.filter(x => (x.city || '').toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()))
    if (clientFilter !== 'all') filteredUsers = filteredUsers.filter(x => (x.client || '').toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()))
    if (departmentFilter !== 'all') filteredUsers = filteredUsers.filter(x => (x.department || '').toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()))
    setUsers(filteredUsers);
  }, [locationFilter, clientFilter, departmentFilter, setUsers]);
```

Then, you can make your handleFilterChange method really simple.

```
  handleFilterChange = (type) => (e) => {
    const searchTerm = e.target.value;
    switch (type) {
      case 'location':
        setLocationFilter(searchTerm)
      case 'department':
        setDepartmentFilter(searchTerm)
      case 'client':
        setClientFilter(searchTerm)
    }
  }
```

Instead of using the data attribute, you could just build your event function in the `onChange`. For example:

```
<select 
  id="locationSelect" 
  defaultValue={locationValue} 
  value={locationValue} 
  onChange={handleFilterChange("location")}
>
  <option value="all">All</option>
  {locations.map((x) => {
    return (
      <option value={x}>{x}</option>
    )
  })}
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you very much :)